# Add Index column to dataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, datatable

Suppose I have the following json to display in my DataTable:

```
 // JSON structure for each row in this example:
    //   {
    //      "engine": {value},
    //      "browser": {value},
    //      "platform": {value},
    //      "version": {value},
    //      "grade": {value}
    //   }
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
      "columns": [
        { "data": "engine" },
        { "data": "browser" },
        { "data": "platform" },
        { "data": "version" },
        { "data": "grade" }
      ]
    } );
```

What I want is, Add an Index Column to this data table for number the row.
Something like this :

```
 "columns": [
        {"data" : "Index"},      <------- this should number my rows 
        { "data": "engine" },
        { "data": "browser" },
        { "data": "platform" },
        { "data": "version" },
        { "data": "grade" }
      ]
```

Note: I don't have any Index as data passed in my Json(Although I can do that, is there any better solution to handle this in my Javascript itself? )

Help appreciated..!

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    return  meta.row + 1;
} },
```

Answer (score 3):

The concept is that you have to create the initial "Index" values either in javascript or in the server. The values can be zero or just empty strings or whatever (there is no need to calculate a counter or something). For example you can create an index column in javascript after you have received the data:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        data[i].index = 0;
    }
```

So now that you have the index column in your data you declare it as the first column of your table:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  .....
  "columns": [
    { "data": "index" },
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    { "data": "platform" },
    { "data": "version" },
    { "data": "grade" }
  ]
} );
```

Now the index values are all 0. To create the real index values that will be shown in the table you need to add an event handler that listens to the ordering and searching of the table. On these events the real index values will be calculated as described in the
[datatables example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html):

```
datatable_object.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    datatable_object.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

When the table is searched or ordered (ordering is done by default when the table is created - see default value of the order option), the innerHtml of the "Index" cells will be calculated based on the index of the row.

Answer (score 2):

Need to use DT_RowIndex for indexing rows. Like this - ## Heading ##

```
"columns": [
{ "data": 'DT_RowIndex'}, // row index
{ "data": "engine" },
{ "data": "browser" },
{ "data": "platform" },
{ "data": "version" },
{ "data": "grade" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the code below to your datatables

```
{ 'data': 'id', defaultContent: '' },
"columnDefs": [   ////define column 1 , make searchable false 
    {
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0

    },
```

Below is the updated code:

```
 var table=$('#example').dataTable( {
     "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
     "columns": [
         { 'data': 'id', defaultContent: '' },
         { "data": "engine" },
         { "data": "browser" },
         { "data": "platform" },
         { "data": "version" },
         { "data": "grade" },
     "columnDefs": [   ////define column 1
         {
             "searchable": false,
             "orderable": false,
             "targets": 0
         },

     ]
});
```

And the following line will add number to your `id(index)` column:

```
if (t.data().length != 0) {
    t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            t.cell(cell).invalidate('dom');
        });
    }).draw();
```

Live example: http://live.datatables.net/woboviqi/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    { "data": "platform" },
    { "data": "version" },
    { "data": "grade" }
].unshift({"data" : "Index"})
```

---

Or by using an temp array

```
var cols = [{
    "data": "engine"
}, {
    "data": "browser"
}, {
    "data": "platform"
}, {
    "data": "version"
}, {
    "data": "grade"
}];

cols.unshift({
    "data": "Index"
})

....
"columns": cols
```

Comment: It says Requested Unknown parameter  "Index" for row 0. And the Index numbers are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this URL: [Data table Index column](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html)

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code you can refer to:

1. My DataTable is complete custom.
2. I'm fetching data from the  database using Ajax and CodeIgniter.

---

### HTML

```html
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table_id_dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr No</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr No</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### JS Script

```js
var temp_table = $('#table_id_of_dataTable').DataTable({
  "language": {
    "zeroRecords": "No records found."
  },
  "ajax": {
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "<?php echo base_url('Controller/method'); ?>"
  },
  "responsive": true,
  "columnDefs": [
    {
     "searchable": false,
     "orderable": false,
     "targets": 0
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],
  "columns": [
    { "data": null }, // <-- This is will your index column
    { "data": "column_2_element_name_given_in_controller" }, 
    { "data": "column_3_element_name_given_in_controller" }, 
    { "data": "column_4_element_name_given_in_controller" }, 
    { "data": "column_5_element_name_given_in_controller" }
  ]
});

// Here we create the index column in jquery datatable
temp_table.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
  temp_nuggets_table.column(0, {
    search: 'applied',
    order: 'applied'
  }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
    cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
  });
}).draw();
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

That is simple... This work for me.

```
Cell: function ( data, type, full, counter ) {
        return  data.index + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enter link description here

```js
Try this: 
var table=$('#example').dataTable( {
     "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
     "columns": [
        {
                    "data": null, "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return meta.row + 1;
                    }
         },
         { "data": "engine" },
         { "data": "browser" },
         { "data": "platform" },
         { "data": "version" },
         { "data": "grade" }
     
});

table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
    }).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

enter link description here

```js
Try this: 
var table=$('#example').dataTable( {
     "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
     "columns": [
        {
                    "data": null, "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return meta.row + 1;
                    }
         },
         { "data": "engine" },
         { "data": "browser" },
         { "data": "platform" },
         { "data": "version" },
         { "data": "grade" }
     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set below for add index column with id

```
let oTable =   $('.dataTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Show All"]],
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{route('route')}}",
                    type:'POST', headers:{  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.date = $('input[name=date]').val();
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    {"data": 'DT_RowIndex', "name": 'DT_RowIndex', searchable: false},
                    {data: 'date', name: 'date', searchable: true},
                ]
            });
```

I use this in my laravel code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).